# JSTL error: unexpected attribute `end' in <x:forEach>

Tags: xml, jsp, foreach, jstl

I am having troubles. It seems the only supported attributes for `<x:forEach>` are `var`, `select` and `jsfc`. However I am seeing other people using tags such as `begin`, `end`, and `step`. For me these tags only work on the `<c:forEach>` iterator.

I'd like to get it working on `<x:forEach>` so I can avoid an ugly workaround.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JSTL `<x:forEach>` tag documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/x/forEach.html) tells otherwise.

Perhaps you still have old JSTL 1.0 libraries or even a prototype around in the classpath. Or you've an older `standard.jar` file around in combination with a newer `jstl.jar` file. In any way, search for `standard.jar` and `jstl.jar` files and replace them by a single JAR file [`jstl-1.2.jar`](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar).

Comment: It seems I do not have either `standard.jar`, `jstl.jar` or `jstl-1.2.jar`. I do, however, have `jstl-11.jar` and `jstl-tlds-1.jar`

Comment: I'd get rid of them. I'd also get rid of any tag declarations in your webapp's `web.xml` -if any, because some poor online tutorials would suggest doing that-. What servletcontainer are you running? What Servlet API version is `web.xml` declared to? Please read our JSTL wiki page for more detail http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Comment: Thanks a lot - seems we are running on 2.4. I'll see If I can't convince some people that updating to 2.5 and jstl 1.2 is what all the cool kids are doing ;)

Comment: Actually, we're already at 3.0 ;) But JSTL 1.1 should work as good. Even more, the documentation which I linked is from JSTL 1.1. In the JSTL wiki page you can find a download link to JSTL 1.1. It exist of 2 files `jstl.jar` and `standard.jar`. Try replacing with it and ensure that you're using the right taglib URI with `/jsp` in the path.